# script to find fields 1 and 5 matching in two files, print combination of fields from both files for those lines

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to find rows where fields 1 and 5 from File 1 match fields 1 and 5 from File 2, and from those rows, print fields 3, 6, 5, and 7 from File 1 and fields 7, 8, and 9 from File 2.

File 1:

```
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49841950  rs201370260            1 
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49841652   rs75811775     0.983883 
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49694713  rs200980145     0.899981 
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49694713    rs1052977     0.894315
```

File 2:

```
5 5_49841950_D I2 D 49841950 0.882 1.05876 0.0112 3.69E-7 0
5 rs28680688 C G 12114 0.842 0.98738 0.0131 0.3326 0
5 5_49694713_I I2 D 49694713 0.864 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6 0
5 rs1052977 A T 49694713 0.982 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6 0
```

I have a script to do this:

```
#! perl -w                                                                                                              
use strict;
use warnings;

my @loci;
open( my $loci_in, "<", "File 2" ) or die $!;
while (<$loci_in>) {
    my ( $chr, $rsID, $A1, $A2, $bp, $info, $or, $se, $p, $ngt ) = split;
    next if m/hg19chrc/;
    push @loci, [$chr, $rsID, $A1, $A2, $bp, $info, $or, $se, $p, $ngt];
}
close $loci_in;

my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open( my $input, "<", "File 1") or die $!;
print "rsID1 rsID2 bp2 r2 or se p\n";
while (<$input>) {
    next if m/chr/;
        my ( $chr1, $bp1, $rsID1, $chr2, $bp2, $rsID2, $r2 ) = split;
    foreach my $locus (@loci) {
        if (    $chr2 =~ /^$locus->[0]$/
                and $bp2 =~ /^$locus->[4]$/)                                                                            
        {
            print "$rsID1 $rsID2 $bp2 $r2 $locus->[6] $locus->[7] $locus->[8]\n";
            next;
        }
    }
}
close($input);
```

I'm having a problem when there are multiple matching fields 1 and 5. For example, File 1 entries

```
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49694713  rs200980145     0.899981 
 5     49841950  rs201370260      5     49694713    rs1052977     0.894315
```

match the two File 2 entries:

```
5 5_49694713_I I2 D 49694713 0.864 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6 0
5 rs1052977 A T 49694713 0.982 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6 0
```

So the output has 4 output lines where it should only have two:

```
rs201370260 rs200980145 49694713 0.899981 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs200980145 49694713 0.899981 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 49694713 0.894315 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 49694713 0.894315 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6
```

Desired output would be:

```
rs201370260 rs200980145 49694713 0.899981 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 49694713 0.894315 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6
```

Does anyone have a perl or awk solution?

Comment: What's your logic on picking one of the multiple join results?  First one?

Comment: You should have also matched first records of the files!

Comment: I forgot to mention, if field 2 matches from files 1 and 2, then the output should reflect fields 2, 7, 8 and 9 from the same entry in File 2

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what `if field 2 matches from files 1 and 2, then the output should reflect fields 2, 7, 8 and 9 from the same entry in File 2` means or how that statement relates to your other requirements. Update your question to show a clear example that demonstrates all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From your description all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { file1[$1,$5] = $3 OFS $6 OFS $7; next }
($1,$5) in file1 { print file1[$1,$5], $7, $8, $9 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
rs201370260 rs201370260 1 1.05876 0.0112 3.69E-7
rs201370260 rs1052977 0.894315 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 0.894315 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6
```

but I've no idea why your expected output is the 2 lines you show in your question instead of the 3 lines above. You need to edit your question to tell us how you want to resolve duplicate keys in file1 and in file2.

Comment: This ignores duplicate keys from the first file but matches them to multiple records from the second.  Uniqueness is not consistently applied.

Comment: @karakfa absolutely correct. Until the OP tells us more about his requirements we're stuck and hopefully this shows him one way in which what he's told us so far is inadequate (or his posted sample input/output is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you want? It's not very elegant with the time I had to play around. Note that arrays start at `0`, so every 'field' number you specified has been reduced by 1.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh1, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'f2.txt' or die $!;

my @fh2 = <$fh2>;

while (<$fh1>){

    my $fh2_elem = shift @fh2;

    my $same = 0;

    for my $col (qw(0 4)){
        if(((split)[$col]) eq ((split /\s+/, $fh2_elem)[$col])){
            $same = 1;
        }
        last if ! $same;
    }

    if ($same){
       print( (join ' ', (split)[2,5,4,6], (split /\s+/, $fh2_elem)[6,7,8]) );
       print "\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
rs201370260 rs201370260 49841950 1 1.05876 0.0112 3.69E-7
rs201370260 rs75811775 49841652 0.983883 0.98738 0.0131 0.3326
rs201370260 rs200980145 49694713 0.899981 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 49694713 0.894315 1.05043 0.0107 4.477E-6
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use hash to filter out duplicates coming from the file.Make a `2D` hash of `1st` and `5th` field and check it before pushing values in `@loci` array.

Try This:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                              
use strict;
use warnings;

my @loci;
my %hash;
open( my $loci_in, "<", "file2" ) or die $!;
while (<$loci_in>) {
    my ( $chr, $rsID, $A1, $A2, $bp, $info, $or, $se, $p, $ngt ) = split;
    next if m/hg19chrc/;
    if ( !$hash{$chr}{$bp} ) {    # check if previously the same record exists
        push @loci, [ $chr, $rsID, $A1, $A2, $bp, $info, $or, $se, $p, $ngt ];
        $hash{$chr}{$bp} = 1;     # otherwise set the record
    }
}
close $loci_in;

#my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open( my $input, "<", "file1" ) or die $!;

#print "rsID1 rsID2 bp2 r2 or se p\n";
while (<$input>) {
    next if m/chr/;
    my ( $chr1, $bp1, $rsID1, $chr2, $bp2, $rsID2, $r2 ) = split;
    foreach my $locus (@loci) {
        if (    $chr2 =~ /^$locus->[0]$/
            and $bp2 =~ /^$locus->[4]$/ )
        {
            print
              "$rsID1 $rsID2 $bp2 $r2 $locus->[6] $locus->[7] $locus->[8]\n";
            next;
        }
    }
}
close($input);
```

**Output:**

```
rs201370260 rs201370260 49841950 1 1.05876 0.0112 3.69E-7
rs201370260 rs200980145 49694713 0.899981 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
rs201370260 rs1052977 49694713 0.894315 1.05306 0.0117 9.224E-6
```